# How can I open a file with line numbers displayed from the command line in 'vi'?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, vi

I've seen so many examples/usages about how to display/hide line numbers in *vi* edit mode.

To turn on line numbers: Type `:set number` in edit mode

To turn off line numbers: Type `:set nonumber` in edit mode

I wonder whether there is any convenient way/option available (that I may not be knowing) to specify/mention this option at the time of opening the file from the command line?

**NOTE:** For example, to go to a specific line inside a file after opening it, we can conveniently say `vi +/<linenumber> <filename>` from the command line.

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question?

Comment: @HTTP500: Hope, by now you might have understood (after reading the answers below) that my question is *subtle* different.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use:

```
vi +"set number" your_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
vi +set\ number <filename>
```

or put "*set number*" to your ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 3):

How about if you create a separate vim settings file for both cases? For example, `~/.vimrc-number` and `~/.vimrc-nonumber`. Then you can launch those like this:

```
vim -u ~/.vimrc-number /some/text/file
vim -u ~/.vimrc-nonumber /some/text/file
```

Or create aliases to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias vimnumbers="vim -u ~/.vimrc-number"
alias vimnonumbers="vim -u ~/.vimrc-nonumber"
```

Answer (score 2):

If wrongly answered your question first. My answer was:

The exact syntax, to jump to a line is :

```
vi +linenumber filename
```

or

```
vi filename +linenumber
```

Where linenumber is a number.

And the correct answer to your question is:

```
vi +set\ number <filename>
```

Which will provides lines number while editing filename.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you answered your own question; Maybe you need to rephrase the question?? :D

`vi +LINENUMBER nameoffile`

Comment: No, the question is little different. Your command jumps to the specified line number after opening the file.  But my question was, how do I specify that option at the time of opening file itself.  Hope you might be clear by now.

Comment: If you mean once you open the file, you want to go to the line then you just type in :linenumber

Comment: Actually, my question was how to specify the option "at the time" of opening file from command-line (but not "after" opening the file).  Hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the line numbers and to jump to the line number you can use the +"set number" and +linenumber :

`vi +set\ number your_file +171`

Answer (score 0):

One can use alias, add `alias vim='vim +"set number"'` to  ~/.bashrc,then `source ~/.bashrc` done.